# I am very new to programming, and this is my first python script assignment. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, new-operator

The program is about giving out the sum of odd and even numbers separately from 1 upto given n term.
***INPUT***

```
print()
print("Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!")
print()
num = int(input("Enter the number of natural numbers: "))
even_total = 0
odd_total = 0
i = 1
while i == num:
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        even_total = even_total + i
        i += 1
    else:
        odd_total = odd_total + i
        i += 1
print()
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i, even_total))
print("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i, odd_total))
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!

Enter the number of natural numbers: 10

The sum of even numbers from 1 to 1 = 0
The sum of odd numbers from 1 to 1 = 0
>>>
```

Comment: You want `while i <= num:` rather than `==`

Comment: @pacharan the output is one digit more than the nth term `Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!

Enter the number of natural numbers: 10

The sum of even numbers from 1 to 11 = 30
The sum of odd numbers from 1 to 11 = 25`

Comment: That is an issue with the print statement at the end (should use `num`) rather than the loop itself. See my answer where I have also suggested that you change this.

Comment: When using a `while` loop, the value after the loop will be the first value of `i` for which the condition evaluated False and the while block **was not** entered (i.e. 11). In fact if you used a `for` loop as I have also suggested, then this problem goes away. But it is still better to use `num` rather than `i` in these `print` statements.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has not completed the intended interations of the loop, which would have been more obvious if you had put some additional `print` statements inside the loop (e.g. `print(i)`) - this is a simple debugging technique that you can use in future. Although in fact there is a clue in the output that you see, where it says `from 1 to 1` rather than something like `from 1 to 10`.

What is happening is that the first time the `while i == num:` is tested, it evaluates `False` (0 is not equal to 10), so the loop is never entered.  If you change the `==` to `<=` here, then this will mostly solve the problem (the loop will go up to and including 10).

Other improvements that you can make will include:

- In the `print` statements at the end, use `num` instead of `i`:

```
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(num, even_total))
```

- Inside the loop, the `i += 1` is done in both the `if` and `else` blocks, so instead you could do a single unconditional `i += 1` after the if...else...

```
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_total += i
    else:
        odd_total += i
    i += 1
```

(I've also suggested using `+=` here with the totals, like you are already doing with `i`.)

- You can also use a `for` loop using `range` instead, and then you don't need to explicitly increment `i` at all. Note that the upper limit of the `range` has to be one greater than the value of `i` on the last iteration.

```
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even_total += i
    else:
        odd_total += i
```

Comment: @AshutoshParashar You're welcome. Have fun learning Python!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `while i==num` with `while i<=num`

```py
print()
print("Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!")
print()
num = int(input("Enter the number of natural numbers: "))
even_total = 0
odd_total = 0
i = 1
while i <= num:
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        even_total = even_total + i
    else:
        odd_total = odd_total + i
    i += 1  #a small optimization to reduce number of lines
print()
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i-1, even_total))
print("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i-1, odd_total))
```

Since, while exiting the while loop your `i` will be greater than `num`, you should print `i-1` in the print statements that follow the loop.

I input `4` and got the following output:

```py
Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!

Enter the number of natural numbers: 4

The sum of even numbers from 1 to 5 = 6
The sum of odd numbers from 1 to 5 = 4
```

Comment: @ fireball.1 But isn't the question asking natural numbers upto 'n'? Shouldn't it be 1 to 4?

Comment: @AshutoshParashar that is just a misprint, the calculation is uptill 4 only. The misprint happens because `i` becomes greater than `num` when it exits the loop and that is what is being printed. I have resolved the same in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The condition for the loop is the problems. It should be:

`while i<= num:`

Answer (score 0):

You should try replacing the `while loop` with a `for loop` like

```
for i in range(1,num+1):
```

calculate even and odd sum..

or replace `while i==num` with either `i!=num+1` (i not equal to num) or (i<=num)

Answer (score 0):

You are using this`while i==num:`  which means that when the `loop` run at first it will take `num=1` which means that your `while i==1` is `true` and the `while loop` breaks. So as farther it can't do the sum.

So you can use `while<=num`

> Here is your code

```py
print()
print("Program to display sum of n terms of odd/even natural numbers!")
print()
num = int(input("Enter the number of natural numbers: "))
even_total = 0
odd_total = 0
i = 1
while i <= num:
    if(i % 2 == 0):
        even_total = even_total + i
    else:
        odd_total = odd_total + i
    i += 1
print()
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(num, even_total))
print("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(num, odd_total))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your test condition of while,
Because, we know, while loop will execute if the condition is true but in your case

```
while(i == num) :
```

here i=1 and num=10 the test condition is false and while loop will never execute.

So, replace  `while i == num:` with `while i<=num:` and it will work fine.

And your last two  print statements are wrong(has nothing to do with logic)

```
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i, even_total))
print("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(i, odd_total))
```

It should be

```
print("The sum of even numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(num, even_total))
print("The sum of odd numbers from 1 to {0} = {1}".format(num, odd_total))
```

There are few more things but as you are a beginner its enough.